# Excel is opening in Protected Mode after deletion of sheets using Java Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi, protected-mode

I have to delete some sheets from an Excel File.

I have used the below code to delete the unnecessary sheets from the Excel file.

```
public static boolean deleteUnnecessarySheets(Workbook workbook,
        boolean authorize) 
{
    if(workbook != null)
    {
        int noOfSheets = workbook.getNumberOfSheets();
        for( int sheetNo = noOfSheets - 1; sheetNo >= 0; sheetNo-- )
        {
            Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(sheetNo);
            String sheetName = sheet.getSheetName();
            if(sheetName.equalsIgnoreCase("User Defined Actions") || sheetName.equalsIgnoreCase("AUTHORIZE"))
            {
                if(!authorize && sheetName.equalsIgnoreCase("AUTHORIZE"))
                {
                    workbook.removeSheetAt(sheetNo);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                workbook.removeSheetAt(sheetNo);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The code successfully deletes the sheets as expected. But on opening the Excel sheet manually I get the following error.

[image]

[image]

How can I prevent this from happening? Or what am I doing wrong?

EDIT: On clicking 'Click for more details'
[image]

Comment: There might be cases where your code delete ALL the sheets. This might be an issue

Comment: I know for sure that there will be at least one sheet remaining. I have even tried
<html>workbook.setActiveSheet(0);</html>
after deleting every sheet

Comment: What does it say when you click on `Click for more details.` ?

Comment: Another reason could be if you have macros or formulas in the remaining sheet that reference cells in some of the deleted sheets?

Comment: What `apache poi` version is used here?

Comment: @AxelRichter apache poi 3.9 version

Comment: Then this is the fault. Version 3.9 is more than 7 years old now and ignoring 7 years of development leads to such problems. As you stated you have tried setting a existing sheet to be the active one after you probably have deleted the sheet which was the active one before. But there also were made changings on related method `private void onSheetDelete` since version 3.9.